# What does the qualifier NOMINAL exactly refer to?

Tags: units, si-units, absolute-units

This question may not specifically belong to the physics domain, and rather perhaps to some engineering one, yet I couldn't find a better place to ask it either, trying my chance here...

From time to time, especially during experimentation, calculation, or simulation related research, I come accross the term **nominal** used to qualify an **attribute** of a parameter, that I can hardly identify which...

For example, recently I was reading a web page on *pipe stress calculation*, which, in a calculator, asked me about three parameters, in exact words:

- 1-) Pressure
- 2-) Diameter
- 3-) **Nominal** thickness ???

Now, I don't have an absolutely clear idea of what this **nominal** thickness may refer to:

- standard thickness
- labelled thickness
- stated thickness
- target thickness
- approximate thickness
- average thickness
- expected thickness
- assumed thickness
- design thickness
- production thickness
- measured thickness
- actual thickness
- simulation thickness
- common thickness
- general thickness  (for fun)

As if that was not confusing enough, as the second part of the question, I'm also confused by the use of the term *nominal* only at the third parameter (the thickness) and not on the Diamater for example, somehow implying that only the *thickness* can possess a nominal value while the other two cannot?

Since this is just an example case, feel free to replace the parameter *thickness* with any suitable physical, engineering, or even social science related parameter you may like. Almost always the same confusion happens on what exactly the term **nominal** refers to.

Any clarifications will be greatly appreciated,
and, please regard the second part of the question as well, and also state if the term was possibly misused on that web page, or was unnecessary to use.

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_Pipe_Size

Comment: @JonCuster thanks but it's not specifically what I was asking for; the *pipe* thing  was just an example usage for the term **nominal**. And the link does not answer questions as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Nominal" value in these sorts of engineering contexts means the following. In engineering contexts, we often label things by their values. A great example is a 2x4 piece of lumber. 2 refers to the width of the board in inches, 4 refers to the height of the board in inches. However, the actual dimensions of a 2x4 board are approximately 1.5" by 3.5". But, probably because of historical reasons, and because it's much faster to say 2x4, we call them "two by fours"s rather than "one point five by three point fives". In this case "2" and "4" refer to the "nominal" dimensions of the boards. That is, we use 2 and 4 to NAME the object.

But with this comes the caveat that the nominal dimensions may not equal the actual dimensions. Now it's obvious to understand how this can lead to confusion, but it also leads to convenience. Sometimes the nominal value will equal the actual value, but that's not always the case. And that's the biggest lesson to takeaway. If you need to know the ACTUAL value of some dimension then do not rely on the NOMINAL value.

Any parameter can be expressed with nominal values. For example, in atomic physics labs we have microwave frequency generates which generate tones tuned to address atomic transitions. For Rb the frequency we use a tone with 6.834 682 610 GHz, but colloquially in the lab we may refer to this as the 6 GHz tone, the 7 GHz tone, or the 6.8 GHz tone depending on how precise we feel about being with our language. In this case the nominal frequency would be 6 GHz, 7 GHz, or 6.8 GHz. There are no other tones in this vicinity so there's no ambiguity regardless of which "nominal" value is used.

It's a typical pattern that the nominal value is a rounded version of the actual value, but this is not always a great rule to follow. I've had the most confusion with nominal vs. actual values when it comes to different types of pipe fitting such as SwageLok. In this case it seems like the nominal value didn't really refer to ANY dimension of the fitting and I had to look at complex tables to figure out which pieces would actually fit together.

This answer is not an endorsement for using nominal values in a confusing way because that can be bad and slow down work. But it's not an endorsement for NEVER using nominal values either, because it is regularly convenient to specify nominal instead of actual values.

edit:
The question asks why sometimes values may be specific with or without the "nominal" qualification. I'll address the specific example in the question. Some calculation for pipe stress requests the following quantities:

- Pressure
- Diameter
- Nominal Thickness
  Why nominal thickness but not nominal pressure or diameter? Again context is critical. For example, if this calculator appears on the webpage for a particular manufacturer or pipes it may be the case that (1) users of the pipes may run any pressure through the pipe (2) customers of the pipes can order custom diameters, BUT (3) the pipes are made from some sort of stock material which only comes in fixed thicknesses which the company enumerates as 1/16", 3/32" etc. Therefore the user of the calculator can select a nominal thickness corresponding to a specific pipe product, but they can freely pick diameter and pressure.

With that said, I'll admit that it's strange that diameter is not nominal but thickness is. Typically a pipe sold by a plumbing or vacuum company would specify products using both nominal thicknesses and diameter. But pressure could be user dependent.

But again, with ALL OF THAT said, about why thickness is nominal but diameter is not, I would say if the calculator can accept any values for diameter, thickness, and pressure, because it is using some analytic or numeric formula to calculate the answer, I would say it doesn't make sense to restrict the thickness supplied to being nominal since the user can put in any thickness they like. In this case, perhaps the tool was written by someone who DOES work with plumbing parts and is just used to seeing the word "nominal" paired with the word "thickness" when using or selecting parts.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I've added two more qualifiers *labelled* and *approximate* after reading your answer. Now however, apart from the **named** vs **actual** value disinction (which's not the case for my question), I find our that the term NOMINAL is almost always either *misused* or at best not a clear descriptor of what is specifically being referred to... I think it should be voided from scientific use. Finally so what would you write into the calculator for the value of thickness? Which meaning would you choose? And why only one parameter is referred to as nominal, while others not?

Comment: It all depends on context. The calculator may be programmed to use actual values when the user supplies nominal values. In that case I would use nominal. In the context of pipes it might be the case that pressure and diameters are conventionally presented using actual values while thickness is conventionally presented using nominal. Again, with nominal it’s all context dependent. This is challenging for newcomers but, at times, can be convenient for experts.

Comment: And about the GHz frequency value issue, afaik *approximate frequency* is a quite clear and satisfactory descriptor. Or may be *design value* vs *actual value* constrast could be used, if that's the attribute he wants to point to...  As an electrical engineer, If one of my colleques refers to using a *nominal 6.7 GHz* , I would really not understand what that really implies.

Comment: Nominal 6.8 GHz is used because we put a label on the box that generates it and the label is “6.8 GHz”. Or in code we name the channel “6.8 GHz”. So “6.8 GHz” is literally the *name* for that channel. Hence “nominal” value.

Comment: Yes that's very to the point! Just like resistors are labelled with their values at the factory according to the their design target value, but actually they will deviate from that design target due to random defects; so the nominal value is the written (stated) value, and the actual value will be a close approximation to it. BUT then as I complain about its misuse, why the thickness called nominal but the pressure not? Pressure is also a stated value, whose actual value will differ based on various random factors, why it's not also called nominal then? That's more annoying now.

Comment: @Fat32 It's a quite nonsensical to assume that when a lot of people have seen your post, that the one who provided an answer voted you down in retaliation for your comments.

Comment: @Fat32 I didn't downvote the question and I don't know why you suspect I did. Like I said above, some quantities conventionally use nominal values and some don't. I'll try to expand on this in the answer.

Comment: @Fat32 also, providing a link to the specific calculator you have an issue with would be helpful, since context is so critical for understanding nominal values.

Comment: Its is now quite to the point: The calculator was probably confusing. Now, some other issues: 1-since the terms *minimal*, *maximal*, and *nominal* rhyme well, I would say nominal would refer to a dynamical attribute of the value taken by the parameter, such as its *average*? 2-Apart from a *factory-set value label* meaning, the term nominal is useless and should be avoided at best. Since all numerical values used in all calculations are indeed just nominal values as stated in the calculations, and not pertaning to the reality ow. So the stated "pressure" is also effectively nominal anyway?

Comment: 1 - No, nominal does not refer to the average, or median or anything statistical like that. It is value used "in name only". It's probably "close to" the average or actual value. 2 - No, nominal names should not be avoided. What should be avoided is *using* nominal values as if they are actual values. If you stack up 4 2x4s in the hope you get an 8" block you'll be disappointed, but I tell you to go to the store to pick up 4 12 foot 2x4s there will be no problem.

Comment: I would say in physics, the  values used in calculations are never nominal, they are always actual with respect to what is being calculated. BUT engineering calculators **may** have conversions between nominal and actual values built into their calculation, in which case the input values really are nominal. But this gets back to the main takeaway: you should never use nominal values in an actual calculation unless you only care about a **very** rough approximate result. That is, don't build a house assuming 2x4s are actually 2" by 4" or you will have a bad day.

Comment: But also, don't go to the hardware store and ask the associate where to find 1.5" by 3.5" boards.

Comment: Could your lumber example be an exception? It seems to me that "2x4" is just a *name alias* from past standards leaking into future. But the calculator was indeed using the numerical value of the entered nominal thickness. Now, for case-1, when I said average, I meant the following: consider the class of 1/8" pipes, here all those pipes will have a value of 1/8" +/- tolereance: if you compute their average you get 1/8", and that's their nominal value, and labelled on the product. So that value effectively represents an expectation or an average among all samples of that pipe of class.

Comment: Coming to case-2: as far as I can say, all physical (and engineering) calculations are based on "stated" values of the physical constants, which are also nominal values. G, $\epsilon_0$, $k$, $h$ ... are all nominal values aren't they? they are not exact but we use them in representation of the exact value. So in a sense they are also nominal values, though not set by  a factory... Therefore all scientific computations are as accurate as the nominals they use are...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141500/discussion-between-jagerber48-and-fat32).